# Error in if (as.character(drlc[c, i]) == "Other Specify") { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed help understanding

Tags: r, for-loop

here is my code:

```r
w <- 5 # or some reasonable number
for (i in 2:189){
  x <- 0 
  for (c in 1:w){
    if (as.character(drlc[c,i]) == "Other Specify") {
      x <- x+1
    } else if (as.character(drlc[c,i]) == "Don't know") {
      x <- x+1
    }
  }
}
```

```
Error in if (as.character(drlc[c, i]) == "Other Specify") { :    missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I have read and understood the error to mean I am not getting a TRUE/FALSE result, but I do not see how that is possible. I have actually looked at the data and see the data. I have typed in the console the comparison (and others to test) and gotten TRUE/FALSE, so why do I not appear to be getting the same TRUE/FALSE in the actual code itself? Thank you for any help and suggestions.

Comment: Welcome we can help you better when we understand your data.  Please share some information about `drlc` preferably as `dput(head(drlc, 5))`

Comment: drlc <- readRDS .... it is a data set comprised of answers: Yes, No, Other Specify, Refuse to answer, etc and an empty/nonresponse is NA. NA's will be rare and I will deal with them later. I inspected this first column and there are none, so I am left confused. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you would you please `dput(head(drlc, 5)) `

Comment: What are you looking for? The output is too long to enter. ??

Comment: Trying to understand your data structure.  One way you would get that error is if your loops exceed the dimensions of your dataframe.  How about `dim(drlc)` and `str(drlc)` are those too much to ask?  I'm just tying to help but honestly I am tired of guessing what your data is so I'm happy to leave your question and frustration alone.

Comment: I must be too novice, I have said what my data is as far as I understand the question. I am sorry I do not understand what you are looking for. Thank you for taking your time to help, sorry I could not answer your questions more specifically.> dim(drlc)
[1] 3788  189

Comment: In all likelihood you just need to change it to be `for (i in 1:3788)` and `for (c in 2:189)` to get rid of the error message.  Are you trying to count occurrences of "Other Specify" and "Don't know" across all the columns?  If so a nested set of for loops is not your best option.

Answer (score 0):

One last try to see if I can understand what you're trying to accomplish...

```r
drlc <- data.frame(
   column1 = 1:100,
   column2 = sample(c("Other Specify", "Don't know", "Other"), size = 100, replace = TRUE),
   column3 = sample(c("Other Specify", "Don't know", "Other"), size = 100, replace = TRUE),
   column4 = sample(c("Other Specify", "Don't know", "Other"), size = 100, replace = TRUE),
   column5 = sample(c("Other Specify", "Don't know", "Other"), size = 100, replace = TRUE),
   column6 = sample(c("Other Specify", "Don't know", "Other"), size = 100, replace = TRUE)
    )


drlc$Other_Specify_Count <- rowSums(drlc[,2:6] == "Other Specify")

head(drlc)
#>   column1       column2       column3       column4       column5       column6
#> 1       1 Other Specify    Don't know Other Specify Other Specify    Don't know
#> 2       2         Other    Don't know         Other Other Specify    Don't know
#> 3       3 Other Specify    Don't know         Other    Don't know Other Specify
#> 4       4 Other Specify Other Specify Other Specify Other Specify    Don't know
#> 5       5 Other Specify         Other         Other    Don't know         Other
#> 6       6    Don't know    Don't know    Don't know         Other    Don't know
    #>   Other_Specify_Count
    #> 1                   3
    #> 2                   1
    #> 3                   2
    #> 4                   4
    #> 5                   1
    #> 6                   0
```